# Elementor Pro Forms - Save Submission Hook

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am familiar with elementor forms new_record hook that I can work with and add some custom actions.

I am looking for a way to add some custom metadata to the save_to_database action elementor has, which saves the form submission in the DB. I have searched and have not found any specific hook that allows me to add custom metadata.
I would like to have on the new_record hook the submission id that was stored and then I can write my own query as needed.
Does anyone know of a way to get the submission id on this hook?

Thanks